# In VS, can a linked file have a partial path?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a library of common code in a Windows folder called "CommonCode". Inside are several subfolders.

For small projects, we simply make a new solution and then use Add Existing... to select the file's we'll need, and the Add->As link so we are editing the originals.

But the problem is that the link has the complete path. My machine has everything inside "Develop" while my co-worker's is in "Mike". So every link breaks when we move the project folder.

Is there a way to use relative links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in the VS IDE tend to behave strangely. In my experience, they tend to get overriden with relative paths when I want absolute, but I have yet to try with a linked file. There are, in essence, two options here which I can see to fix this issue -

The first is that if you're concerned about absolute versus relative pathing, open up the text of the .csproj file. If you've never done this, you'll note it's all in XML. Then hand-edit the entries with the relative path, keeping in mind the [$(SolutionDir) macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.100).aspx) and the "..\" in Windows means "up one level." As long as you don't reimport those links, then VS usually leaves such entries alone, specifically because there are many and more things you can do with a hand edited file (Different references based on platform is probably my favorite trick here)

The second choice, which I recommend a lot more, is to use the functionality of your Content Management (be it Git, SVN, or Mercurial) which lets you embed other repos ("Subrepos" or "Externals") - this will allow you to have edit functionality on the original document, while it's embedded in the filestructure of your project and thus agnostic to the file structure leading up to it. Even Better, you have the common files on their own repo, even if that repo is cloned into it's own place somewhere else on your disk

Comment: Option B sounds like the better long-term solution, although I'll be doing A in the short term. BTW, is there a way to integrate GIT into VS directly so I don't have to use an external client?

Comment: Due to MS trying to support their own Team Foundation Server, it's not doable without third-party plugins. I have not used any of these plugins myself and have no recommendations on any particular implementation, but a rudimentary search of Google reveals that there are multiple options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in a text editor, and find the place where you have added your file.

There you can change the path to be relative the project directory